# NHibernate.HibernateException: No session bound to the current context

Tags: nhibernate, hibernateexception

I am getting this error when I am trying to get the CurrentSession

```
NHibernate.Context.CurrentSessionContext.CurrentSession()
```

at

```
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetCurrentSession()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are responsible for setting the current session on the session context. See [this section](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#architecture-current-session) of the NHibernate documentation. If you haven't done this, then there will be no current session to retrieve.

Answer (score 13):

Like David M said, you need to make sure you are binding your NHibernate session. Here's the way I do it right now in my ASP.NET app:

```
public class NHHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += ApplicationEndRequest;
        context.BeginRequest += ApplicationBeginRequest;
    }

    public void ApplicationBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(NHSessionFactory.GetNewSession());
    }

    public void ApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISession currentSession = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(
            NHSessionFactory.GetSessionFactory());
        currentSession.Close();
        currentSession.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

I create a custom HttpModule that binds my session on every request and then I add this module to my web.config like this:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="NHHttpModule" type="MyApplication.Core.NHHttpModule, MyApplication,
  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />      
</httpModules>
```

I'm sure your configuration is different then this but this is just an example of how I bind my session. Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 11):

Studio 2010 will create 2 httpModules sections, one is for IIS 7. Be sure to register your nhibernate httpmodule in the system.web one too.

Comment: Genius, thanks for this answer, saved me from a massive 'egg on face' incident :)

Comment: I had to put mine in the modules here for it to work:  <system.webServer>
 <modules></modules>
</system.webServer>

Comment: you need to add your HttpModule in web.config in these section <system.web><module></system.web> and <system.webServer><module></system.webServer>